# How do i handle this dropdown using selenium with no select class?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to access this website and after that, I want to click on the Status dropdown and select Active from the dropdown. I think there are no select tags to be used hence the traditional select method is not working. Would be really helpful if anyone can have a look at it!

"""

```
PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.silveroaksp.com/portfolio")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='btn-group show']").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

"""

Answer (score 1):

*To capture all the Webelements in dropdown we use driver.findElements for multiple elements(this return element in the list).
*You can use to method for this. click on Feild and then click on active Web element, Second is you put it in a for each loop and in IFELSE condition put click

1.

```
 PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.silveroaksp.com/portfolio")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='StatusMultiselect']/following- 
sibling::div").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='StatusMultiselect']/following- 
sibling::div/ul/li[2]/a/label/input").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

*This'll work I guess. IF doesn't let me know I'll provide a second option

Comment: Hello Fouzan, thanks for sharing your code. I tried running the code above but I get the same error as I was getting with mine.  ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (329, 676)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with Requests & Pandas:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

final_list = []
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0', 
           'Host': 'www.silveroaksp.com', 
           'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01', 
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
           'Referer': 'https://www.silveroaksp.com/portfolio', 
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
          }

data = '{"prmStatusIds":"PortStatus1","prmIndustryIds":"","prmFundIds":"","AllStatusClickChecker":"0","AllIndustryClickChecker":"1","AllFundClickChecker":"1"}'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://www.silveroaksp.com/portfolio')

    
    r = s.post('https://www.silveroaksp.com/CommonItem/FilterPort', data=data, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    actives = soup.select('div.col-lg-4')
    for active in actives:
        business = active.select_one('img')['alt']
        link = active.get('id')
        r = s.post('https://www.silveroaksp.com/CommonItem/PortfolioInfo', data = '{"PortUrl":"' + link + '","Status":"all"}', headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        try:
            headq = soup.find("label", string="Headquarters").find_next_sibling('span').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            headq = 'unkown'
        try:
            industry = soup.find("label", string="Industry").find_next_sibling('span').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            industry = 'unkown'
        try:
            aquired = soup.find("label", string="Acquired").find_next_sibling('span').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            aquired = 'unkown'
        try:
            website = soup.find("label", string="Website").find_next_sibling('span').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            website = 'unkown'
        try:
            title = soup.select_one('div.about-author').select_one('h4').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            title = 'unkown'
        try:
            description = ' '.join([x.text.strip() for x in soup.select_one('div.about-author').select('p')])
        except Exception as e:
            description = 'unkown'
        try:
            headline = soup.select_one('div.about-author').select_one('strong').text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            headline = 'unkown'
        final_list.append([headq, industry, aquired, website, title, description, headline])

final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['headq', 'industry', 'aquired', 'website', 'title', 'description', 'headline'])
final_df.head()
```

This returns:

```
headq   industry    aquired     website     title   description     headline
0   Chicago, Illinois   Business Services   March 2018  www.brilliantfs.com     Brilliant   Brilliant is a leading provider of temporary a...   Brilliant is actively looking for add-on acqui...
1   New York, New York  Consumer Services   November 2017   caringpeopleinc.com     Caring People   Founded in 1998, Caring People is a leading ho...   Caring People is actively looking for add-on a...
2   Denver, Colorado    Business Services   December 2021   ccsbts.com  CCS Facility Services   CCS Facility Services is a leading provider of...   CCS is actively looking for add-on acquisition...
3   Atlanta, GA     Consumer Services   August 2021     unkown  Drive Automotive Services   Drive, headquartered in Atlanta, GA, is a lead...   Drive is actively looking for add-on acquisiti...
4   Woburn, Massachusetts   Healthcare Services     December 2020   www.geriatricmedical.com    Geriatric Medical   Founded in 1945, Geriatric Medical is a leadin...   Geriatric Medical is actively looking for add-...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I am getting the output as you have mentioned above but my objective is not to print these options above. I just want to filter the websites mentioned on that page by applying the 'active status' filter and then I am scraping only those filtered website links.

Comment: @saimmohd: The code above will only return the active ones, with PortStatus1. As you are saying you want to also scrape the resulting links (for active status entities), I amended my code to also scrape those, and return a dataframe with all results.